# Limit of a non monotone sequence of subsets of a set

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

In book " Real analysis Theory of measure and integration " . There's a definition of limit of a monotone sequence of subsets of a set X . Then it gives the definition of limit of a sequence of subsets of a set X using limit inferior and limit superior . Where $\lim_{n\to\infty} inf A_n= \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N} } \bigcap_{k\geqslant n} A_k $

I'm trying to evaluate the limit of this sequence .
$A_{2n-1}=[0,\frac{1}{2n-1} ]$ ,, 
$A_{2n}=[0,2n]$.

I expanded some terms , i found that $\lim_{n\to\infty} inf A_n=\{0\}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} sup A_n =[0,\infty]$ .

The problem is how can i mathematically write this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your notation isn’t quite right: the limit inferior is the set $\{0\}$, not the number $0$, and the limit superior doesn’t include $\infty$: it’s just $[0,\to)$ (or, in the notation that you’re using, $[0,\infty)$).

You have

$$A_n=\begin{cases}
[0,n],&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\
\left[0,\frac1n\right],&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\;.
\end{cases}$$

Notice that

$$\ldots\subseteq A_5\subseteq A_3\subseteq A_1\subseteq A_2\subseteq A_4\subseteq A_6\subseteq\ldots\;,$$

This helps to give a picture of what’s going on.

Let $n$ be any positive integer. Then certainly $2k\ge n$ when $k\ge n$, so

$$[0,2m]=A_{2k}\subseteq\bigcup_{k\ge n}A_k$$

for each $m\ge n$, and therefore

$$[0,\to)=\bigcup_{k\ge n}[0,2k]\subseteq\bigcup_{k\ge n}A_k\subseteq[0,\to)\;,$$

where the last inclusion follows from the fact that $A_k\subseteq[0,\to)$ for each $k\ge 1$. Thus,

$$\bigcup_{k\ge n}A_k=[0,\to)$$

for each $n\ge 1$, and therefore

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_n=\bigcap_{n\ge 1}\bigcup_{k\ge n}A_k=\bigcap_{n\ge 1}[0,\to)=[0,\to)\;,$$

the set of non-negative real numbers.

Once again we’ll let $n$ be any positive integer, but this time we’ll use the fact that $2k+1\ge n$ when $k\ge n$. This means that

$$\bigcap_{k\ge n}A_k\subseteq A_{2m+1}=\left[0,\frac1{2m+1}\right]$$

for each $m\ge n$ and hence that

$$\bigcap_{k\ge n}A_k\subseteq\bigcap_{k\ge n}\left[0,\frac1{2k+1}\right]=\{0\}\;.$$

Since $0\in A_k$ for all $k\ge 1$, this implies that

$$\bigcap_{k\ge n}A_k=\{0\}$$

for each $n\ge 1$ and hence that

$$\liminf_{n\to\infty}A_n=\bigcup_{n\ge 1}\bigcap_{k\ge n}A_k=\bigcup_{n\ge 1}\{0\}=\{0\}\;.$$

Comment: You're right the first is {0} , sorry a misprint . The second is the extended real values .